# display data in the form2 based on the button you clicked in the form1

Tags: c#

do you know how to display a data in the form2 based on what button you clicked in the form1? Like for example there are three buttons in the form1 and you have to click 1 out of the three button. After you click a button, a form2 will appear with an information about the button that you clicked in the form1.

I used visual studio anyway. Thank you

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors

Comment: define a second constructor and pass the parameters you want through it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a string variable in Form1, and in the event handler of your buttons on Form1 set your string variable with the needed information you want to send to Form2.

Then, whenever you want to show Form2, send that string variable to the constructor of Form2. Of course, you must add a constructor in Form2 with a string parameter.

Your code should look something like this:

```
string info;

private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    info = "Information you need to send";
}

private void ShowForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form = new Form2(info);
    form.Show();
}
```

Your Form2 should look something like this:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private string info;

    public Form2(string s)
    {
         // "s" is the string sent from form1 containing the needed information
         info = s;
    }

    // Use the string info to show in any event handler in Form2 let's say the Form_Load
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(info, "Data from Form1");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must define two forms, and in the first button event, call the builder of the second form and pass the information about the button.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{ 
    string data1= "data button 1";
    List<int>  data2 = new list<int>();
    data2.add(1);
    data2.add(3);
    Form2 frm2 = new Form2(data1,data2);  
    frm2.Show();  
}
```

Now `form2` in constructor:

```
List<int> listnumber =new List<int>();
string button_Name=string.Empty;
public Form2()
{
}

public Form2(string button_name,List<int> data2)
{
    this.button_Name = button_name;
    this.listnumber = data2;
}
```